# Export Table to Excel

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, sql-server-2008-r2

How do i Export a Table from Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 to an excel sheet, thanks

Comment: Unless you're looking to do this procedure programmatically this question is better suited for SuperUser.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [SQL Server Import and Export Wizard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms141209.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

1. Open Microsoft Excel
2. Click Data Tab and select "From Other Sources"
3. Select "From SQL Server"
4. Type the server name and click "Next".
5. Choose the database, click next and choose the table

Regards,

Jun

Answer (score 0):

You can also copy and paste it from Sql Server Management Studio in the results view.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this tool http://www.dbtransfer.de/Products/DbTransfer